# Krita: Selection line automatically surrounding the object shape on a layer

Tags: selections, krita

I'm a total Krita noob here.

I'd like to know, in Krita, what's the way to select an object that is on a transparent layer, so that the selection line automatically follows the shape of the object?

Once you select an object and move it, the selection doesn't stick to the shape, contrary to what Photoshop does, which can be very convenient sometimes.

It would be a bit like select the transparent part of layer with the eyedropper then invert the selection to only grab the object, but it's a bit tedious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Krita expert, however right clicking a layer and then choosing *Select Opaque* seems to do what you want. It appears to be similar to GIMP's *Alpha to Selection*, or in Photoshop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking on a layer to load it as a selection.

Comment: oh ok, I thought it would be simpler, like in Photoshop, thanks a lot!

Comment: actually once you select an object and move it, the selection doesn't stick to the shape, contrary to what Photoshop does, there must be another way, hard to find though

Comment: @moonboots, maybe just move the layer first before you make the selection.  Sometimes you have to change your workflow for different software, because they simply don't always work in the exact same way.

Comment: ok I've created a shortcut, seems to work   ;)